# Exchange 2010 hub transport configuration –InternalSMTPServers

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, exchange

I did the following configuration in powershell on my hub transport server for anti-spam settings.

```
Set-TransportConfig –InternalSMTPServers 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2
```

Initially, when i did a

```
Get-TransportConfig | fl InternalSMTPServer
```

I would get

```
InternalSMTPServer : {}
```

Now, i want to remove the 2 IP entries for the internalSMTPServer, how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-TransportConfig –InternalSMTPServers $null
```